# Removing wildcard words using jQuery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, text, input, preg-replace

Hey guys, I hope I am able to explain this as easy as possible. Basically I am compiling a list and to do so I need to remove a load of text after a certain trigger word.

[Example of what I am trying to achieve is here](http://filthycandy.co.uk/replace/)

Say I have just pasted a bunch of text in my text box, I want everything removed apart from the first username.

**And example would be...**

r-u-f-f-i-a-n reblogged this from youaref0rsaken

youaref0rsaken reblogged this from loveeoutoflust

loveeoutoflust reblogged this from yourwatchfuleye

**Which I would want to turn in to**

r-u-f-f-i-a-n

youaref0rsaken

loveeoutoflust

With using a textbox with the input, a button and a textbox which would display the output. I have tried doing this using jquery and php preg_replace but cannot get it to function correctly.

Is anyone able to help me with this?

Comment: it sounds like you need help buliding a regular expression? is that example above accurate? I mean are you constantly replacing "reblogged this from" or will this change. rather what is the delimiting between the usernames?

Comment: it will constantly be "reblogged this from *wildcard*" obviously *wildcard* being replaced with the random username. I am hoping to do this in list form as there will be around 50-100 lines per input.

Comment: @matchw when using .replace(/ reblogged this from (.*?)/, "")); it only replaces the first letter of the wildcard username

Comment: i'd have to see slightly more code than that, but look at my answer below. does this help any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>look into javascripts replace funciton</strike>

```
string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)
```

as an example check out this fiddle using the code below http://jsfiddle.net/vwhCx/
note: if the concept of a regexp is new to you the only thing to know here: /reblogged this from/g is that the //g means globeably, or more than one match.

```
<div id="boxy-1"> r-u-f-f-i-a-n reblogged this from youaref0rsaken youaref0rsaken reblogged this from loveeoutoflust loveeoutoflust reblogged this from yourwatchfuleye </div>

<button>transform</button>
<script type="Text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    //get text from box
    var str = $('#boxy-1').text()
    //empty box
    $('#boxy-1').empty();
    //insert formatted sting 
    $('#boxy-1').append(str.replace(/reblogged this from/g, ' '));
  });
)};

</script>
```

UPDATE

based on your comment I have altered my code to work on a text area

use this

```
<textarea id="boxy-1"> r-u-f-f-i-a-n reblogged this from youaref0rsaken youaref0rsaken reblogged this from loveeoutoflust loveeoutoflust reblogged this from yourwatchfuleye</textarea>

<button>transform</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    //get text from box
    var str = $('#boxy-1').text()
    //empty box
    $('#boxy-1').empty();
    //insert formatted sting 
    $('#boxy-1').val(str.replace(/reblogged this from/g, ' '));
 });
});
```

new live example: http://jsfiddle.net/K3LZU/

**LAST EDIT**

if you are trying to display it as a list, or newlines try str.replace(/reblogged this from/g, '\n') the \n indicating a newline

Comment: @matchw this does not work as I shall be inputting new text in to the div every time (this is why I need a textarea), even when I replace the div with a textarea the button no longer works.

Comment: @matchw yeah this works, but the problem I am having here is the formatting, am I able to contact you over email or facebook so I can chat you to in real time? If not all I can suggest is heading over to

http://filthycandy.co.uk/replace/test1.php

and looking at my code, everything works apart from when I delete the text in the input box and replace it with new text and press "remove text" it reverts me back to the old text and deletes the bits i just added in. I am trying to ammend your code to give me the formatting which I need but am not doing very well.

Add Dekky Balboa on Facebook

Comment: normally, i would say yes, but it is late for me. I am cleaning up and on my way to bed. perhaps you want to look into the .match() function of javascript to grab the string and than insert it in a text-area with formatting. i show a brief, unrelated, example of using match here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880036/swapping-two-divs/5891593#5891593

good luck, I'll check back in tomorrow morning.

Comment: I edited my answer at the bottom to show an example of inserting a newline in a textarea between values. I hope some of this helps you on the path to figuring this out.

Comment: @matchw I will take a look, I have made my own script on fiddle for you to look at, maybe this will give you a better idea on what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: @matchw http://jsfiddle.net/WGde6/9/ - fyi i'm also in the UK and hoping to get this code done before I go to bed and I would be willing to send you a couple of quid over paypal for helping me out!

Comment: okay, so I couldn't sleep. change .html() to .val() should do the trick here updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skLAe/

Comment: @matchw yeah man I worked that out, all working now :) thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '/reblogged this from [\w]+/';
$string = "r-u-f-f-i-a-n reblogged this from youaref0rsaken youaref0rsaken reblogged this from loveeoutoflust loveeoutoflust reblogged this from yourwatchfuleye";
echo preg_replace( $pattern, '', $string);
```

will give you as result

```
r-u-f-f-i-a-n youaref0rsaken loveeoutoflust
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WGde6/9 this will explain what I am wanting to do in easy terms, could you view it and give it a play about?

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the first word, you can do something simple like this:

```
$s = 'youaref0rsaken reblogged this from loveeoutoflust';
$a = explode(' ',$s);
echo $a[0];
```